# How to make infinite loop with awk

Tags: loops, awk, infinite

I have a program:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
}
{
        print "hello"       
}
END {
}
```

It prints hello and then waits for enter to be pressed and then again prints hello.
i want to make it infinite without asking for enter.
Please comment!

Comment: Do you mind to comment why do you want to do such thing?

Answer (score 6):

Agreed with @SiegeX

```
yes | awk '{ print "hello" }'
```

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{
  while(1)
    print "hello"
}
```

Comment: aahh, forgot to mention that cant use any control statement

Comment: @AN1 apparently, you also forgot to mention this is homework. If you can pipe a command to awk who's output is infinite, your code will work.